# Python Parse.Find If exist

Tags: python, json

I have created a python parser that will access a webpage then take information from divs inside the source like a small API. But with different accounts there are more DIVS and it comes back as a false reading.

Whenever i go to an admin account it always says {"PlayerExists": false}.

MY code:

```
if 'PlayerName' in self.request.GET:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
            docType = '{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}'
            PlayerName = self.request.GET['PlayerName']
            gamertagava = self.request.GET['PlayerName']
            output = {}
            try:
                msPageHandle = urllib.urlopen('http://nflplayers.mobi/'+PlayerName+'.html')
                msPage = msPageHandle.read()
                msPageHandle.close
                parse = ET.fromstring(msPage)
            except:
                output['PlayerExists'] = False
                self.response.write(json.JSONEncoder().encode(output))
                return      
output['AdminTeam'] = parse.find('.//*[@id="AdminTeam"]')   
output['AdminLaunchTeam'] = parse.find('.//*[@id="AdminLaunchTeam"]')   
output['Old Skool Player'] = parse.find('.//*[@id="Old Skool Player"]') 


            output['PlayerName'] = parse.find('.//*[@id="PlayerName"]').text
            output['Playerscore'] = parse.find('.//*[@id="Playerscore"]').text
            if output['Playerscore']=='--':
                output['PlayerExists'] = False
                output['Playerscore'] = 0
            else:
                output['GamertagExists'] = True
                output['Playerscore'] = int(output['Playerscore'])
```

The admins have an extra DIV so i dont know if this is the problem. and this is it. Any Help is welcome.

```
 <div id="AdminTeam">
        <label>Admin&nbsp;Team</label>
        <div class="Badges">

            <div id="AdminLaunchTeam" class="Badge"></div>

            <div id="Old Skool Player" class="Badge"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks. Remi

Comment: What is the error you get? What doesn't work?

Comment: i basically get Internal Error 500, or Playername:False

Answer (score 0):

In your XML there is no element that matches these XPath expressions:

```
.//*[@id="PlayerName"]
.//*[@id="Playerscore"]
```

So this line will throw an error:

```
parse.find('.//*[@id="PlayerName"]').text
```